# Trying to integrate braintree-web into Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, braintree

I am trying to use the Braintree SDK (braintree-web) in my Angular2 app.  I'd really appreciate any pointers on how to get this working.  I think it is because I am not importing the braintree-web module, but I can't figure out how to to that either.  I can find any exports in the whole module.

Here is where I am:

I've imported the braintree-web library and a typings file I found.

```
ng install --save braintree-web
npm install @types/braintree-web@3.0.1
```

I tried to hack the JS example Braintree provides into a Angular2 TS Component, but I keep getting an error:

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in
>   ./UpaccountComponent class UpaccountComponent - inline template:5:7
>   ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: this.braintree.setup is not a function

Here is the .ts file.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


declare var braintree:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'up-btcheckoutform',
  templateUrl: './btcheckoutform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./btcheckoutform.component.css']
})
export class BtCheckoutFormComponent implements OnInit {
  braintree = require('BrainTreeWeb');
  // braintree = require('braintree-web');
  integration: any

  constructor() {   }

  ngOnInit() {
    var c = this;
    var clientToken = "CLIENT_TOKEN_GOES_HERE";
    braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
      container: "payment-form",
      onReady: function(int) {
        c.integration = int
        }
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.integration.teardown();
  }


}
```

Comment: Are you using angular-cli? If so, which version?

Comment: Yes.  A pretty recent version.  After they switched over to WebPack.  I will edit this when I get back to my dev machine and can get a version number.

Comment: I guess I can't edit a comment.  Here is my cli version info...
>ng -v
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.8
node: 6.5.0
os: win32 x64

Comment: so how did the answer help?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about the usage of braintree-web specifically, but if you're using webpack, remove the lines `declare var braintree:any;` and `braintree = require('BrainTreeWeb');`

You'll also need to add the braintree-web/index.js file to the bundle, unless they've got a UMD module.

From a quick glance at braintree-web, it looks like `braintree.setup(..)` isn't a function. Something like this might be equivalent:

```
braintree.client.create({ 
      authorization: "long-token-string"},
      (err, client) => {
            // Do stuff here
            client.request({..});
      });
```

With the package installs, you'll need to have added `--save-dev` to the types install.

Comment: Note: I work at Braintree. Wanted to add support to this answer in saying that it looks like you are pulling in v3 of our JS SDK but attempting to use v2 methods in your code. I would try integrating via [v3](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v3) and see if this solves your issue.

Comment: @BrianK I was able to incorporarte this into angular2 using v3 thanks to this answer from Fiddles.  However, now I get an error saying, 'Cannot read property 'create' of undefined' on the braintree.client.create method. I am able to console log and view the version if I do a braintree.version in my component. So I know I'm definitely pulling in BrainTree into my component. I'm just trying to figure out why braintree.client is undefined. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I have integrated the brain-tree the same way as you have done and it works.
I've just installed one more command

first install

```
npm install @types/braintree-web@3.0.1er
```

then install

```
npm install --save braintree-web@2.30.0
```

and use

```
braintree = require('braintree-web');
```

Again if it asks for `braintree` is not defined then remove `declare var braintree:any;`
and replace bellow code

```
braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
    container: "payment-form",
    onReady: function(int) {
        c.integration = int
    }
});
```

with

```
this.braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
    this.container: "payment-form",
    onReady: function(int) {
        c.integration = int
    }
});
```

Edit:

just declare the var after import `declare var braintree:any;` if your working with angular 4 then declare `declare var require: any;`

Comment: When I implement it, it says "cannot find property setup of undefined"

Comment: after i install npm install @types/braintree-web@3.0.1er and try to import using import * as braintree from 'braintree-web'; I get error message "File '...../node_modules/@types/braintree-web/braintree-web.d.ts' is not a module."

Comment: @Marverik just declare the var after import `declare var braintree:any;`

Comment: @Maverik don't import braintree  instead require the file in component as `braintree = require('braintree-web');`

Comment: if require is throwing an error then declare it as `declare var require:any;`

Answer (score 3):

You can also import it via:

```
import * as braintree from 'braintree-web';
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this:
[Refrring 3rd party JS libraries in angular 2](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/include-external-javascript-libraries-in-an-angular-2-typescript-project/)

It's a universal solution. You don't even need to use any npm packages. Just simply refer BrainTree JS libarary in index.html and follow the steps documented in above link. It's applicable for any JS library.